# ERROR: In <declare-styleable> LinearLayoutICS, unable to find attribute divider Holoeverywhere

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, divider, android-appcompat, holoeverywhere

i use appcompat

Getting this with HE 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT. Here are some parts of my build.gradle:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    // ...
   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
       compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
       compile 'org.holoeverywhere:addon-preferences:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
   }
```

Build output:

```
   :weheartit:processDebugResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':weheartit:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt package -f --no-crunch      -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M    /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S          /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/res/all/debug -A /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/assets/debug -m -J /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/source/r/debug -F /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/libs/weheartit-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.weheartit --output-text-symbols /Users/felipecsl/Data/Projects/whi-android/weheartit/build/symbols/debug
```

Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    ERROR: In  LinearLayoutICS, unable to find attribute divider